# How do I get the public key from a PFX certificate using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, certificate, public-key, pkcs#12

I am trying to extract the public key from a certificate using Powershell. However, whenever I use the Powershell command `Get-PfxCertificate` it only outputs the Thumbprint of the certificate and not the public key. How can I get it to output the public key?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To retrieve the public key from a PFX certificate using Powershell, use the following command:

```
(Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath mycert.pfx).GetPublicKey()
```

To convert the public key to a hex string without hyphens you can use this command:

```
[System.BitConverter]::ToString((Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath mycert.pfx).GetPublicKey()).Replace("-", "")
```

Answer (score 5):

Be aware, that `Get-PfxCertificate` temporarily stores your private key at `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`, where **everyone** could read it.

If that is not a desirable behavior, than you should probably use either `import` method or constructor of the `X509Certificate2` .NET object with `EphemeralKeySet` as a key storage flag, which indicates that private key should be created in memory and not persisted on disk when importing a certificate, e.g.:

```bsh
$Cert = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$FullPathToCert = Resolve-Path -Path .\cert.pfx
$Password = Read-Host 'Password' -AsSecureString
$X509KeyStorageFlag = 32
$Cert.Import($FullPathToCert, $Password, $X509KeyStorageFlag)
$Cert.GetPublicKey()
```

#### Notes

- `EphemeralKeySet` flag supported by *.NET Framework 4.7.2*, *.NET Core 2.0* and above;
- `$X509KeyStorageFlag = 32` is just a shorthand for the `$X509KeyStorageFlag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::EphemeralKeySet`

#### Further reading

- `X509KeyStorageFlags` enumerator spec https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keystorageflags
- Eight tips for working with X.509 certificates in .NET: http://paulstovell.com/blog/x509certificate2