# windows cmd/Powershell how to export public key from private key pfx file without password prompt?

Tags: cmd, passwords, export, public-key, pfx

"[Export a Certificate from pfx](https://dev.to/iamthecarisma/managing-windows-pfx-certificates-through-powershell-3pj)" can be made seamless, without user requiring to enter password.

Powershell 6.1+ commandlet allows `-password` switch for [Get-PfxCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/get-pfxcertificate?view=powershell-7.1).

For earlier versions, a [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38134750/how-do-i-get-the-public-key-from-a-pfx-certificate-using-powershell) was:

```
powershell (Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath Private.pfx).GetPublicKey()
```

, where user had to enter password on command prompt, or get error:
`Get-PfxCertificate : The specified network password is not correct.`

The password had to be typed on prompt; copy/paste not accepted. There was no switch to supply password to the command either.

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Pfxdata` does the same job, allowing password to be processed inscript, without user intervention for password protected pfx files:

```
set /p pwd="Enter password: "
pwdstring
set pwd=convertto-securestring \"%pwd%\" -asplaintext -force
powershell Export-Certificate -Cert ((Get-PfxData -FilePath Private.pfx -password (%pwd%)).EndEntityCertificates[0]) -FilePath Public.cer
```

Tested on Win 10 CMD